# How do Card packs work

Tags: fort-conquer

I know card packs supposed to give you 8 cards but are they the same cards you get when buying the cards out the regular way. Last time i bought an 8 pack I only received one dragon. Are certain cards, like the dragon cards, limited in the possible maximum amount you can get?

If different than buying regular packs; what is the more or less percentage distribution when buying a card pack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always get only one dragon at each pack, and there is a slight chance of getting very good cards, buts its better to buy seperate cards.